# Parse.com. Custom subclass properties are not saved. iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have my class for UserFavourite that looks like this:

```
UserFavourite.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "Product.h"


@interface UserFavourite : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, copy) Product* product;
@property (nonatomic, copy) PFUser* user;

+(NSString *)parseClassName;

-(id)initWithProducts:(Product*)product
                 user:(PFUser *)user;

@end

UserFavourite.m

#import "UserFavourite.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation UserFavourite

@dynamic product, user;

+(NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"UserFavourite";
}

-(id)initWithProducts:(Product*)product
                 user:(PFUser *)user{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.product = product;
        self.user = user;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

This is the code where I do insert:

```
//Getting product from Parse
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Product"];
UserFavourite *uf = [[UserFavourite alloc] init];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"NhKrnlzeeN" block:^(PFObject *product1, NSError *error) {

    [uf setUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
    Product* pr = [[Product alloc] init];

    pr.name = [product1 objectForKey:@"name"];
    pr.category = [product1 objectForKey:@"category"];
    pr.price = [product1 objectForKey:@"price"];
    pr.ingridients = [product1 objectForKey:@"ingridients"];
    pr.protein = [product1 objectForKey:@"protein"];
    pr.fats = [[product1 objectForKey:@"fats"] integerValue];
    pr.carbo = [[product1 objectForKey:@"carbo"] integerValue];
    pr.calories = [[product1 objectForKey:@"calories"] integerValue];
    pr.likes = [[product1 objectForKey:@"likes"] integerValue];
    pr.quantity = [[product1 objectForKey:@"quantity"] integerValue];
    pr.status = [[product1 objectForKey:@"status"] integerValue];
    pr.objectId = product1.objectId;


    [uf setProduct:pr];
    NSLog(@"uf %@", uf);

}];



[uf saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        // The object has been saved.
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

I want to save this to Parse server, but those properties are not saved to the table as you can see on the picture:
[image]
I have also initialised this subclass in AppDelegate as well.
What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` is an asynchronous method call. The following call to `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` will be called before the prior one completes, saving `uf` prior to any modifications being made it it.

To fix this, move the save into the completion block above.

Comment: I am doing this all in AppDelegate, and I noticed when I do debugging, the execution does not get past first line of getObjectInBackgroundWithId. It actually does not even do any modifications. I dont really understand this situation.

Comment: Also, you need to be sure that the user is logged in and that [PFUser currentUser} is not nil.